# GeoDjango wanting coordinated in range [-180 -90, 180 90]?

Tags: python, geodjango

Here is my model:

```
import datetime
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class UserLocation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    coords = models.PointField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

    @classmethod
    def get_latest_location(cls, user):
        return cls.objects.filter(user=user).latest()

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = 'date_created'
```

When I try to query it like so:

```
coords = Point(x=34.4208305, y=-119.6981901) # in california
UserLocation.objects.distance(coords)
```

I get this error:

```
DatabaseError: Coordinate values are out of range [-180 -90, 180 90] for GEOGRAPHY type
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_distance_sphere" during inlining
```

Why is it wanting them in the range [-180 -90, 180 90]? That doesn't make any sense to me...

Answer (score 1):

Considering a sphere (assuming the earth is round like a ball), using spherical coordinates (r, phi, tau), the given ranges are sufficient to identify every point on the sphere. For a detailed explanation of the coordinate system consult for instance Wikipedia at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system.

If you have larger angles, you just fit them to the interval, e.g.

```
if (phi > 180):
    phi -= 360
elseif (phi < -180):
    phi += 360
```

and similarly for tau.

Comment: I don't follow... my coordinates are in the form `x, y`, there is no angle involved.

Comment: I assume, the (x,y)-corrdinates (look like WGS84) are transformed to spherical coordinates in order to measure the distance? Why are you storing the East/West-value in y? Wouldn't it be x/longitude? What I'm guessing is: x and y may be reversed.